# Jquery - Possible to use .attr or similar on html input text instead of regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the video thumbnail of a Vimeo or Youtube iframe as the user pastes the iframe code into the textarea box. First step is getting the video ID number from the iframe src attribute.

I know how to get the textarea.val() on paste but the result is a string and I would like to access the iframes src attribute example http://player.vimeo.com/video/video_ID and then use

```
var n = srcFrame.lastIndexOf('/');
var result = srcFrame.substring(n + 1);
```

to get the video_ID

Is there a way to use .attr or similar on the value returned by .val() (maybe I have to convert the string to object?) or am I forced to do some acrobatic string manipulations?

Example user input would be:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/THIS_NEEDED" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/65616948">Demo 01 2013</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/kr">KR</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prop('src')` to get the src, and if you're sure it doesn't end with `/`, you can split on `/` and pop of the last value:

```
var ID = $('iframe').prop('src').split('/').pop();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Js36Q/)

**EDIT:**

To get the iframe's src out of a HTML string, which is what you have, you parse it as HTML by appending it to an empty element, and go from there :

```
var holder = $('<div />').append($('textarea').val());
var ID = $('iframe', holder).prop('src').split('/').pop();

alert(ID);
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work when the iframe is inside a textarea. I updated the fiddle to represent my issue better. http://jsfiddle.net/Js36Q/1/

Comment: An iframe can't be inside a textarea, that would make it just the value of the textarea, and not real DOM elements.

Comment: @adeneo - that is what he is trying to work with . . . code for an iframe, pasted by a user into a textarea.

Answer (score 1):

attr should work

```
$("iframe").attr("src");
```

Should get you what you want.  This will work if there's only one iframe on the page.

Comment: get undefined when the iframe is inside <textarea></textarea>

Answer (score 1):

I think that people may be misunderstanding your question . . . you are not talking about an actual `iframe` element on your page, but the source code for an `iframe` element from another page, that has been pasted into a textarea on your page, correct?

If I am reading you correctly, yes, there are several options in the answers above that involve converting the string to a DOM object in order to have access to it's attributes, but that seems a little clunky to me, considering that you could simply extract the value that you want from the string.

It may be easier for you to code than figuring out a good regex or other string manipulation, but I'm not convinced that it's the best way.  But then again, I'm personally not a huge fan of creating DOM objects that are not actually going to be used as part of the page, but that could just be me.   :)

**Edit:** Adding a regex/string manipulation solution:

This regex will capture the `src` attribute from the string:

```
var srcPattern = new RegExp("(?:src=\")([^\"]+)");
```

- `(?:src=\")` is a "pre-match" that ensures that only the value that follows it will be matched
- `([^\"]+)` will match the actual URL for the src attribute.

Match the value from the textarea input:

```
var textareaValue = $("#textareIDValue").val();
var srcMatch = textareaValue.match(srcPattern);
```

To access the actual `src` value, you will need to get the second item in the `srcMatch` array that was returned, using this:

```
var srcValue = srcMatch[1];
```

The first item in the returned array (index `0`) will have the complete match (`src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/THIS_NEEDED` in the sample that you provided), but you want just the URL (the part captured by `([^\"]+)` . . . `http://player.vimeo.com/video/THIS_NEEDED` in the sample), so you want the second item in the array (index `1`):

So, now you have the `src` value, you need to grab the last part of it, so use the string `split()` function to get all of the "pieces" of the URL:

```
var srcPieces = srcValue.split("/");
```

Since you want only the last one, use `length - 1` to get the last item from that array:

```
var videoId = srcPieces[(srcPieces.length - 1)];
```

`videoId` will be the value that you are looking for (`THIS_NEEDED` in the sample).

NOTE: I left out a lot of the error checking that you will want to do (e.g., did the `match` function return any values, is the length of the split `src` value greater than 0, etc.) and there are ways of shortening it be combining steps, but this should give you a good start and should make all of the steps more understandable.

Total code without commentary:

```
var srcPattern = new RegExp("(?:src=\")([^\"]+)");
var textareaValue = $("#textareIDValue").val();
var srcMatch = textareaValue.match(srcPattern);
var srcValue = srcMatch[1];
var srcPieces = srcValue.split("/");
var videoId = srcPieces[(srcPieces.length - 1)];
```

Comment: You are correct in your understanding. Not sure how to convert the string to an object. Do you have a suggestion for easy string manipulation to get the src value? Im petrified of regex :P

Comment: Give me a second . . . will add a sample to my answer.   :)

Comment: Solution added.  Note: Mataniko's answer shows how you can convert the string into a DOM object, using jQuery.  Again, though, under most circumstances, I'm not a fan of creating DOM objects that aren't going to actually be used.

Comment: thanks. I appreciate the detailed answer and have learned from it. Even though I may go this route I must accept Adeneo's answer as it solves the problem to the question asked. Ill try to get you points in other ways :)

Comment: No sweat . . . just glad to help get you a solution.   :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only solution:

```
var s = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/THIS_NEEDED" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe> <p><a href="http://vimeo.com/65616948">Demo 01 2013</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/kr">KR</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>'

var id = $(s).attr("src").substring($(s).attr("src").lastIndexOf('/')+1, $(s).attr("src").length)
```